# Generate 2D distribution avoiding loops

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to construct a 2D Gassuian-like distribution on a (Nx, Ny) array of the form:

```
 return np.exp(-0.5*((x-xp)**2 + (y-yp)**2)/SG**2)
```

where (x,y), in this case, would correspond to [i, j] matrix indices.

I am doing this by looping through a `np.zeros((Nx,Ny))` matrix and updating its values with the defined function.

Basically, I would like to know if there is a way to generate a similar result but avoid the for loops that I am using here. My intuition tells me that `np.meshgrid` or `zip(x, y)` should do it but I have been unable to replicate it.

(I would like to avoid using the auxiliar distribution_Gp function and to be able to use directly normaldist function).

Here is my sample code of how I am using it all together:

```
import numpy as np
def normaldist(x, y, Nx, Ny, xp, yp, SG=1):
    """2D-mesh (Nx,Ny) with Gaussian distribution values."""
    z = np.exp(-0.5*((x-xp)**2 + (y-yp)**2)/SG**2)
#     /(SG*np.sqrt(np.pi*2.)))  # non-normalized
    return z


def distribution_Gp(Nx, Ny, xp, yp, SG=1):
    """Fill up the C0(Nx, Ny) array for the specified values and conditions."""
    mask = np.zeros((Nx, Ny))
    for j in range(0, Ny):
        for i in range(0, Nx):
            if(i <= Nx*Ny*normaldist(i, j, Nx, Ny, xp, yp, SG)):
                mask[i, j] = normaldist(i, j, Nx, Ny, xp, yp, SG)
    return mask
Nx = 11
Ny = Nx
arr_img = distribution_Gp(Nx, Ny, Nx//2, Ny//3, SG=2)
```

Comment: What about reading the [standard Numpy tutorials](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html) first? It explains how to vectorize your operations. If you want a fast code, calling a CPython function in a hot loop is definitively a bad idea (very slow). Not to mention the CPython *interpreter* optimizes almost nothing. You can start by vectorizing `mask` without considering the conditional and then play with `np.where`

Comment: You can do this with "array broadcasting", e.g. `x = np.arange(Nx); y = np.arange(Ny); mask = normaldist(x[:, np.newaxis], y[np.newaxis, :], ...)` Note that the `Nx` and `Ny` variables are not used in `normaldist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using lambda and with two arguments and meshgrid it is possible to replicate `distribution_Gp`.

Using lambda and avoiding using the intermediate function:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, Nx)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, Ny)
arr = np.zeros((Nx, Ny))
f = lambda x, y: normaldist(x, y, Nx//2, Ny//3, SG=2).T
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
result = f(X, Y)
```

which produces the same result as:

```
result = distribucio_de_puntsG(Nx, Ny, Nx//2, Ny//L, SG=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A matrix with values sampled from a normal distribution can be accomplished by :

`np.random.normal(mean, std, (Nx, Ny))`

where `Nx` and `Ny` are shapes of the output, as in your code.

If you want to apply any custom function to a matrix then this can be accomplished by:

```
arr = np.zeros((Nx, Ny))
f = lambda x: x + 3
result = f(arr)
```

Comment: I do not want to get RANDOM sample values from a normal distribution but I want to get the values extracted from my defined function. I may not explain myself properly.

Comment: Added a comment that solves Your case. I highly recommend reading the standard numpy tutorials, as stated by Jerome above

Comment: I know about the vectorization with lambda. However, I would like to perform operations through [i]*[j]; which thankfully to your comment I see now that I can use np.meshgrid properly.